# Maximum Number Of Process Exceeded in Oracle 11g

Tags: java, oracle, sharepoint, weblogic

I was getting the error message that the maximum number of processes (150) is exceeded. So i increased it to 1000 and restarted the server. But it still got full in less than an hour.

When i look into the sessions table i see lots of inactive sessions created by SYSTEM, like 950 of them.

I have no idea why these sessions are created and i can't kill all of them all the time.

We have 4 people in our team an two of them use sharepoint 2013 and connecting with wcf. Other two is using weblogic and have 200 connection pooling limit each. All of the team members are using toad.

Does anyone have any idea how to stop creating these inactive sessions.

Comment: when you say created by SYSTEM do you mean `USERNAME` in `v$session` is SYSTEM? what is in `USERNAME, PROGRAM, MACHINE, OSUSER` for all of these sessions?

Comment: USERNAME is SYSMAN, PROGRAM is OMS, MACHINE is the server itself, OSUSER is [MachineName]$ for all of them.

Comment: Seems to be Oracle Enterprise Manager stuff. Try to stop / reconfigure / remove it if not needed...

Comment: @igr You are right, i stopped its service and all the sessions have been killed. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with Oracle 11gR2 running on W2K8-R2 and it turned out to be the dbconsole process trying over and over through SYSMAN to connect to a non-existent Oracle Enterprise Manager (OEM) instance.  If you aren't using OEM, disable the 'dbconsole' service in Windows Services.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do execute the below SQL

`select USERNAME,ACCOUNT_STATUS from dba_users where username='SYSMAN';`

Check to see if the account status is locked or not. If it is, it could be caused by sysman password problem and you need to reset in DB and your enterprise manager and unlock the account.

Comment: It says OPEN in the ACCOUNT_STATUS field.

Comment: Does your DB have a policy of locking account if the login password is not right?

Comment: Yes, i have. But like i said the problematic user is not locked.

Comment: Understood. The problem you described is usually caused by the password issue, which should cause the account to lock. As you said, in your case, the account is not locked. But I would still suggest resetting the password in both DB and OEM. Worth a try.